# Where do i find the function key for a locally deployed Azure Function?

Tags: azure-functions

Have a deployed azure functions with docker compose locally using net6.0.

Need to call the function from another local api service, adding the x-functions-key in the header.

The function has the auth attribute: AuthorizationLevel.Function

How do i find the default or master key for the locally deployed azure function?

I have tried various dummy keys and all sent 401 unauthorized back.
I have also found a folder called DataProtection-Keys with a xml file containing keys, but these did not work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a solution I copied from: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/4147#issuecomment-1660784713

in your `compose.yaml`, include the following:

```yaml
    environment:
      - AzureWebJobsSecretStorageType=files  # looks for secrets under /azure-functions-host/Secrets/
```

in your Dockerfile, include the following three lines:

```
# for local run - create a known key ('test') for x-functions-key
RUN mkdir -p /azure-functions-host/Secrets/
RUN echo '{"masterKey":{"name":"master","value":"test","encrypted":false},"functionKeys":[]}' > /azure-functions-host/Secrets/host.json
```

Now you can use the value `test` for your `x-functions-key`

Answer (score 0):

As you are using `Authorization.Function` in your function, you need `Function key` to run the deployed function.

Once you deploy the function to Azure function:

- Go to your function app in Azure portal:

[image]

- Open the deployed `function(eg: Http Trigger)=> Function Keys`.

You can find the `default key`:

[image]

Copy the `value` of the `default` key and you can use it as value of `x-functions-key` while calling the function.

[image]

Comment: How is the key bound to the application in the deployment to Azure? I do not see why I must deploy the application to run it locally.

Comment: My bad!! I thought you were asking for deployed function. To run the function locally, there is no need of function key.

Comment: How do i disable authorization of the key when running locally in a docker container?